# How to run \IfSubStr on a macro parameter that may contain a newline

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I have a macro where parameters may contain newlines but when one does, everything seems to break.

How can I prevent this problem?  I also want \IfSubStr to look for a match anywhere in the parameter string regardless of newlines.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mytest}[8]{%                                                                                                                         
  \IfSubStr{#1}{\#HIDE}{Hidden.}{#1}
}


\begin{document}

Four tests follow:

1. \mytest{Some string that is not hidden.}

2. \mytest{Another string that is not hidden.}

3. \mytest{Some string that is hidden.\#HIDE}

4. \mytest{A string that does not work and breaks everything because it has a newline\newline in it}

Tests completed.

\end{document}
```

Output I get with pdflatex is:

Four tests follow:
1. Some string that is not hidden. . Hidden. ests completed.

I don't understand what is wrong with test 2 not printing either.  And I can't use a [1] for the number of arguments to \mytest for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `\xstring` uses `\fullexpandarg` as default, that means the text in its macros are full expanded the hard way with `\edef`. That does not follow LaTeX's protection mechanism and macros can break. In your case you do not need an expansion at all, because the strings are given plainly, thus the example modifies `\mytest` to call `\noexpandarg`. It's put into a group in order not to disturb other packages that might use `xstring`'s macros.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{#1}{\#HIDE}{Hidden.}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

Four tests follow:

1. \mytest{Some string that is not hidden.}

2. \mytest{Another string that is not hidden.}

3. \mytest{Some string that is hidden.\#HIDE}

4. \mytest{A string that now works and does not break    
   everything because of a newline\newline in it}    

Tests completed.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

See also the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) of package `xstring`, section "3.1.1 The commands `\fullexpandarg`, `\expandarg` and `\noexpandarg`".

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the \noexpandarg but didn't know about grouping.  The problem is that I have macros that need to be expanded in the TRUE FALSE arguments to \IfSubStr.  How can I just not expand the string argument?

Comment: @user2177594: These arguments are not affected by the expansion mode, see the cited section. It lists the macros and shows the affected arguments in purple.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake.  The problem is that if I add a \begingroup and \endgroup to my command pdflatex goes into an infinite loop!  It's something about my command being called from inside a tabularx.  But it seems to work without the group, though I don't like it.

Comment: @user2177594: The scope of local settings ends at the end of an environment.

Answer (score 1):

The number following the `\newcommand{<cmd>}` defines the number of arguments. You're only using 1, so don't put `[8]`. Currently, you're grabbing the first 8 tokens as the arguments to `\mytest`, and those are

1. `{Some string that is not hidden.}`
2. `\par`
3. `2`
4. `.`
5. `\mytest`
6. `{Another string that is not hidden.}`
7. `\par`
8. `3`

...which then leaves you starting with `.` as the next input after calling `\mytest` the first time.

In the example below I've made `\newline` a no-op so that `\IfSubStr` can work with its argument better:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xstring}

\let\storenewline\newline
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{{%
  \let\newline\relax%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{\#HIDE}{Hidden.}{\let\newline\storenewline #1}%
}}


\begin{document}

Four tests follow:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \mytest{Some string that is not hidden.}

  \item
  \mytest{Another string that is not hidden.}

  \item
  \mytest{Some string that is hidden.\#HIDE}

  \item
  \mytest{A string that does not work and \newline breaks everything because it has a newline in it.}

  \item
  \mytest{A string that should be hidden and \newline has a newline in it.\#HIDE}
\end{enumerate}

Tests completed.

\end{document}
```

This may be *specific* to your case where you use `\newline`. Other macros may also cause problems, for which [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175710/5764) is better.

Comment: Package `xstring` applies `\edef` on the arguments, that also breaks many other macros. See `\noexpandarg`, or `\normalexpandarg`, if the text is stored in a macro.

Comment: I had used [8] because [1] gave me an error.  I don't know why, but it's working now.